# Can't add polyline on map after pushing its coordinates which were obtained via separate AJAX query?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xmlhttprequest, overlays

```
  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.652988, 25.611792),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

    var lines = new google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                editable: true
                });

    nline = function setPolyline(points) {
    var path = lines.getPath();
    path.clear();
    path.push(points);
    lines.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    var target = document.getElementById("info_panel");
    target.style.display = "none";
    });

    /*
    google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'click', function() {
    alert("you clicked polyline");
    });
    */
  }
```

After doing an XMLHttpRequest from a SQL Database, another function calls the setPolyline function (which is located inside the map initialization function because the "map" and "lines" variables are only local and not global) passing as argument an Array of latlng's.

The setPolyline function takes that array, clears the polyline's (named "lines") path, pushes the latlng array into the path, and when getting to the setmap instruction simply fails to do anyting at all...

Is there a nesting problem or what?...please help i've been trying to figure this out for the last 6 hours...

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `lines.setPath(path)` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.652988, 25.611792),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

    var lines = new google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                path: linepth,
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                editable: true
                });

    nline = function setPolyline(points) {
    var linepth= [];
    var path = lines.getPath();
    path.clear();
//    path.push(points);
    linepth.push(points);
    lines.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    var target = document.getElementById("info_panel");
    target.style.display = "none";
    });

    /*
    google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'click', function() {
    alert("you clicked polyline");
    });
    */
  }
```